# Derivative of polynomial in GF(16)

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, finite-fields

how can I find the derivative of the following polynomial in $GF(2^4)$:
$\alpha x^4+x^3+\alpha x^2+\alpha^2 x+1$ ?

Comment: what do you mean to derive it?

Comment: @user254665 He probably means differentiate.

Comment: @user254665 Obviously he means differentiate

Comment: @Ahmed Use the formal definition of derivative.

Comment: sorry, I just edited my question and the mistake has been corrected

Comment: Surely you know how to find the derivative of a polynomial! Remember that as coefficients (but not as exponents) $2=0$, $3=1$, $4=2=0$ et cetera.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This means that the derivative is: $x^2+\alpha^2$. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Correct, Ahmed. I would like you to encourage to post that as an answer as well. Two reasons: 1) you may get more feedback and/or rep points (for whatever purpose). 2) site hygiene will improve, whenever a question is answered :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of the following polynomial: $\alpha x^4+x^3+\alpha x^2+\alpha^2 x+1$ in $GF(2^4)$ is: 
  $x^2+\alpha^2$.